# accessibility test fails: Elements must have their visible text as part of their accessible name

Tags: html, jaws-screen-reader

I have a button that has visible text 'Make default', like the following button

< button type="button" aria-label="Click to make this your default card"> Make Default </button>

I want to give accessible name 'Click to make this your default card' using aria-label (to give context for button)
Jaws screen reader reading it perfectly. but accessibility test rule (https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/general/G208) fails with following error:

"Serious: Elements must have their visible text as part of their accessible name"

Since accessible name (aria-label) does not containing display name ('Make default') so causing the issue.

But I can not change accessible text to include display text (I have to use accessible text: 'Click to make this your default card', because requirement are like that)

So, is there any way to fix this issue. so that I can have specified accessible text and display name without having above accessibility issue.

I hope, I have explained the problem clearly.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you share what code you have for the button. Would make it easier to answer your question

Comment: <button type="button" aria-label="Click to make this your default card"> Make Default </button>  this button where I want to specify accessible text: Click to make this your default card (as specified in button with aria-label) and display label: Make Default

Comment: However accessibility test says: interactive elements labeled through their content have their visible label as part of their accessible name: https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/general/G208

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [WCAG](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/general/G208) standards have these rules in place for a reason. But a workaround is possible using `aria-labelledby`. Insert your helper text in a hidden label and give the `id` of that label to `aria-labelledby`. Like so:

```html
<button type="button" aria-labelledby="button_message"> Make Default </button>
<label id="button_message" class="hiddenlabel">Click to make this your default card</label>
```

Label could be hidden by

```css
.hiddenlabel {
  display: none;
}
```

Note: Visible text should match or be contained in the aria-label. You can maybe modify visible text if this comes up again

Comment: I am sorry, I did not mention this, there can be a list of credit cards which will be loaded on the page. 
and complete accessible text will as: 

"Current Saved Card ending with __cardNumber__ Card type __cardType__ Name on Card __nameOnCard__ Expiry Date __expiryDate__ . Click to make this your default card."


In the above accessible text, "__cardNumber__", "__cardType__", "__nameOnCard__" and "__expiryDate__" will be updated based on card details.


If I follow this approach, I have to create multiple hidden elements (one for each credit card).

Comment: Yes. You will have to do that. That's the downside of working around the rules. You can make a reusable component for this purpose and use it everywhere in your application. The text can be passed as input to that component

Comment: Also If you are displaying a list of cards you should use ngFor. Write the code for the component just once and supply it with diffrent values/objects stored in an array.